# How can I display large amount of active organizations within the platform?

Tags: dropdown, data, dashboard

Currently when the user uses the platform is able to choose an active organization (within his organization) and which data he wants to include. The current solution indicates a narrow bar under the top navigation which informs the user regarding data included. The issue appears when the user has more than viewport width active sub-organizations / organizations.
What would be the best solution to display it?

Dropdown or maybe just pop-over on hover effect? Or maybe some other solution?

If its pop-over - the user has to "hover" to preview all included data and this can be hard to remember.

If it's dropdown - If the bar gets to 3-4 rows I think having such a large and visually "heavy" element would feel distracting.

Any feedback/insights?
[image: dropdown example]

Comment: What the platform used for? What is the relationship between organizations? What data is being included and for what purpose? I'm having a hard time putting this into context. Could you rewrite it using an example / anecdote? Thanks

Comment: Dear Nicolas, thank you again for your interest. It is a data-driven platform for the HR sector. This component of the platform is responsible for choosing the organizations / sub-organizations.  The user choice will affect the visible data. So for instance if user will choose just Company - will see the data relevant just to this organization. If the user will choose Company 1 and Company 2 - will see the data relevant for both organizations.

Comment: The relationship between organizations is that they are all part of bigger organizations so ie. Unilever or Nestle have many small organizations within their brand

Comment: is the user choosing companies at a global level (affecting everything displayed under dashboard, surveys, analysis) or local (only affecting analysis)?

Comment: also, what does the company dropdown do in the top right?

Comment: it affects globally. Dropdown in case there are more companies to display than 1 row... ( I'm not sure about this dropdown though). Additionally, I just got informed that paragraph - "the changes you make will apply to xx" is not necessary anymore. So the bar would just indicated data included which is good.

Comment: How frequently are the users selecting and deselecting companies as they accomplish their tasks?

Comment: it's considered as an advanced feature for now

Comment: Advanced as in only certain users have access to it?

Comment: advanced because is not used as frequent

Comment: Why does the user need to know the companies selected at all times? It seems like it's a setting that doesn't change much, wouldn't they know this by memory and refer back to the company selector if they forget?

Comment: another way of doing this is by showing the companies within the data you are displaying. For example, perhaps part of the dashboard is a breakdown of the total per company, effectively showing where the data is coming from.

Comment: so you think the bar above doesn't make much sense? but if I would display it for every component if it's global it would take a lot of space if many are selected...(ie. we have question cards and responses analysis) i think if the information is global is better rather to implement it in one place rather than repeat it in many places...

Comment: The ribbon bar is commonly used for notifications and alerts, so it’s not properly used in this case. My questions are trying to understand why the feature of shoeing all selected companies at all times is needed. Trying to understand the underlaying need.

Comment: Having this information displayed more visibly should lower the risk for users to unintentionally make changes to the wrong organization, makes it clearer which data they are currently viewing and allows us to easier debug issues based on screenshots

Comment: It sounds like the reason to have the organizations listed in the screen at all times is more for developers to debug. Perhaps you introduce a step in the editing process for the user to confirm the list of organizations their edit will be applied to.

Comment: Showing a list of organizations in the screen does not mean the users will read it. They are notorious for not reading. Making it more actionable, as a step to confirm after an edit, will make it more noticeable.

Comment: Thank you, Nicolas. I will share this idea with my product team and let's see what they think :)

Answer (score 1):

Visual options I see:

1. Shorten it. E.g. "Company, HQ, IT..."
2. Aggregate it. E.g. "13 companies"
3. Abstract it to bigger organisations if possible. E.g. "Nestle (10/14)"

You would probably want a way for the user to view the full list with an accordion or a tooltip/popover.

But I also agree with Nicolas that a big bar that is always visible will probably be dismissed as not important by a lot of users.